# "The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'" when using stdin.readLineSync()

Tags: string, dart, dart-null-safety, null-safety

i'm new at dart. I don't know what kind of mistake i have made, but this code didn't work.
Is a simple code, just read the age in terminal and say it's underage or over 18.

```
import 'dart:io'; 

main(){
  print("Entre com a sua idade: ");
  var input = stdin.readLineSync();
  var idade = int.parse(input);

  if(idade >= 18){
    print("É maior de idade");
  }else{
    print("É menor de idade");
  }
}
```

And i get this error:

```
algoritmo01.dart:15:25: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
  var idade = int.parse(input);
```

Comment: Read through https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety It will explain this error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Welcome to Dart. What you are experience is the new null-safety feature (introduced with Dart 2.12.0) where variables by default cannot contain the value null. This is statically checked so you will get an error even before your program are executed.

In your example the problem is the following line:

```
var input = stdin.readLineSync();
```

If we check the manual we can see this method have the following signature:

```
String? readLineSync (
    {Encoding encoding = systemEncoding,
    bool retainNewlines = false}
)
```

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-io/Stdin/readLineSync.html

`String?` means it is a nullable type and is therefore allowed to contain any String or null. If the type instead was `String` it would mean the result can only be a `String` and never `null`.

This means that your variable `input` now has the type `String?`. This (introduced with 2.12.0) is a problem if you take a look at the second line of your example:

```
var idade = int.parse(input);
```

Since the signature of `int.parse` is:

```
int parse (

    String source,
    {int? radix,
    @deprecated int onError(
        String source
    )}

)
```

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-core/int/parse.html

Which takes a `String` (which can therefore never be `null`). You are therefore not allowed to give your `String?` as parameter to a method which only handles `String`. The opposite would have been allowed (if method takes `String?` and you give it a `String`).

So what can we do about this situation? Well, you need to handle the case of `null` or tell Dart that it should just crash your program if `input` are `null`.

So you could handle it like:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print("Entre com a sua idade: ");
  var input = stdin.readLineSync();
  
  if (input != null) {
    var idade = int.parse(input);

    if (idade >= 18) {
      print("É maior de idade");
    } else {
      print("É menor de idade");
    }
  } else {
    print('Input was null!');
  }
}
```

As you can see, this is allowed even if `input` are technically still of the type `String?`. But Dart can see that your `if` statement will prevent `input` to have the value `null` so it will be "promoted" to `String` as long as you are inside this if-statement.

Another solution is to tell Dart that it should stop complain about statically errors about `input` and just assume `input` is `String` when compiling the code:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print("Entre com a sua idade: ");
  var input = stdin.readLineSync()!;
  var idade = int.parse(input);

  if (idade >= 18) {
    print("É maior de idade");
  } else {
    print("É menor de idade");
  }
}
```

(The change is the `!` added after `readLineSync()`)

Dart will in this case instead add its own `null`-check and crash the program if `stdin.readLineSync` does give a `null` value. This is to ensure that we are still never going to give `int.parse` a null value which could make your code crash somewhere else. By adding the `null`-check where we get the questionable value, we can ensure we fails fast and at the place where things was not as we expected it to be.

You can read a lot more about null-safety in Dart here (also linked to by Stephen): https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is right. But there is another alternative solution. You can use "if null" operator like this :

```
var idade = int.parse(input ?? "-1");
```

So full code will looks like this :

```
import 'dart:io'; 

main(){
  print("Entre com a sua idade: ");
  var input = stdin.readLineSync();
  var idade = int.parse(input ?? "-1");

  if(idade >= 18){
    print("É maior de idade");
  }else if(idade < 18 && idade > 0){
    print("É menor de idade");
  } else {
    print("entrada errada");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I**t isn't because of null safety?
As I've reading to transform a string taken from a stdout to int you have to do the next:

```
import 'dart:io'; 
main(){
  print("E**ntre com a sua idade: ");
  //You use ?? to indicate "otherwise" and '0' to use 0 if it is null.
  var input = stdin.readLineSync()??'0';
  //Here you also add otherwise '0' if it is null
  var idade = int.parse(input ?? '0');
  if(idade >= 18){
    print("É maior de idade");
    }else{
    print("É menor de idade");
       }
}
```

Comment: Second `??` null check doesn't make sense, since you already ensured non-nullability of input.

Comment: Hello! It is because of an advertisement: "Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't"       Here it says that String can be nullable while string? isn't (This is bc of null-safety) so you add ??'0' in that way if the user doesn't sends anything it transforms into a '0' and it doesn't crashes. It is the same for int.parse, null  safety will tell you tat int is nullable while int? isn't. That's the reason why there's a  second ?? '0'