# not able to complete the program

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I'm new to dart and having a hard time figuring out things. so, I just need some help completing the program below. I have no idea where I'm going wrong.
All I'm getting is an error related to **null safety**

**question** :-
Write a program to obtain a number N and increment its value by 1 if the number is divisible by 4 otherwise decrement its value by 1.

```
import 'dart:io';

void main(){
  String? input = stdin.readLineSync();
  int number = int.parse(input);
}
```

This is all that came to my mind, I know the logic, but I'm stuck at getting the user input and converting it.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment suggest, in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66696954/15747954) is explained how Dart will handle if `stdin.readLineSync` does give a `null` value. So this should work, notice the `!` at the end of `stdin.readLineSync`.

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  var input = stdin.readLineSync()!;
  var number = int.parse(input);
}
```