# How to read an integer input from the user input in dart

Tags: dart, stdin

I actually don't know how to take a integer input from the input console. Then I tried this after a little research.

My Code:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  stdout.write("Enter a number: ");
  int num1 = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  print(num1);
}
```

- But it doesn't work, showing an error message,

```
 ERROR: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
```

- Then finally I came to know that in dart2.12+ versions dart introduced null safety. Any suggestion to do it properly in the null safety environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [readLineSync()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-io/Stdin/readLineSync.html) method returns a `String?`. The `?` symbol indicates this variable may be null.

On the other hand, the [int.parse()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/parse.html) method expects a `String`, without the `?` symbol. This means it doesn't know how to handle if the result from the readLine method comes null.

The easiest way to solve this is to give a default value in case the result comes null:

```
int num1 = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync() ?? '0');
```

The `??`  operator makes the expression evaluates to the right side, if the left side is null. So giving it a default value it won't have to bother with a nullable type.

There are other operators you can use. You can read more about it in the [Dart documentation about it.](https://dart.dev/null-safety)

Comment: Thanks @Naslausky, it also worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import 'dart:io';

void main()
{
    // Asking for favourite number
    print("Enter your favourite number:");

    // Scanning number
    int n = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());

    // Printing that number
    print("Your favourite number is $n");
}
```

If this not work I think you should try this answer [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66695339/the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-string-w)

Comment: No brother it doesn't work your code's actual logic is same to mine. Dart is now enabled with null safety it's not working.

Comment: check the answer I have link here, that might be helpful

Comment: Thanks brother @Divyesh_08 the answer you linked worked!