# Why can't we assign String to stdin?

Tags: dart

I'm new at dart. I think that it's about the new dart version that I can't assign **String** to **stdin.readLineSync()**. Can Someone Pls tell me the alternatives?

This is just a basic calculator where I'm trying to add two numbers.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';


void main() {
  print("Enter first number: ");
  String? num1 = stdin.readLineSync();
  print("Enter second number: ");
  String? num2 = stdin.readLineSync();

  print(num1 + num2);

  
}
```

Comment: Hello, can you add the error message?

Comment: The linked answer is not exact the same problem but very similar since your problem is not with `int.parse` but with using the `+` operator on a `String?` type. But the answer describes in details the problem you are having with nullable types and the different solutions for that. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the alternative way how you do:

`In Dart programming language, you can take standard input from the user through the console via the use of .readLineSync() function.`

```
import 'dart:io';

void main()
   {   
    print("Enter first number");
    int? n1 = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);

    print("Enter second number");
    int? n2 = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!); 

    int sum = n1 + n2;
    print("Sum is $sum");
   }
```

and here it is clearly explained about your problem ["The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'" when using stdin.readLineSync()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66695339/the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-string-w)