# Error Message: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter

Some can help me. My message error is The property 'message' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

[image]

Comment: Try to change from 'snapshot.data.message' to 'snapshot.data.message!'

Comment: It is possible `snapshot.data` will be null, check if it is null, then provide `snapthshot.data?.message??"default message"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'" when using stdin.readLineSync()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66695339/the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-string-w)

Answer (score 1):

If you know, `snapshot.data.message` is not `null`, you can do :

```dart
errorMessage: snapshot.data.message!,
```

If it `snapshot.data.message` can be `null`, a solution would be :

```dart
errorMessage: snapshot.data.message ?? '',
```